# It it okay to close laptop cover while HDD and power light are still on?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

When I shutdown my Win 10 laptop, the screen goes black but for about 15/20 seconds the HDD light and the power light are still on.

Will it be a problem to close the cover before these lights turn off or will that interrupt the shutdown?

Comment: I've seen some machines where it hibernates if you close the lid very quickly, not sure if thats still an issue. You can test by seeing what it does when you wake it up.

Comment: Its best you don't as this will depending on the timing interfere with the `shutdown` process...